# Can not push code to the project - error 403

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I'm facing a problem when I try to push my code to the project. Git shows error message:

```
Push failed
Remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
unable to access 'https://gitlab.name.com/project/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have permission to the repository, my SSH key is not expired (I also created a new one). I can't push but I can fetch code from the project. No idea what's going on.
I use Androd Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using `https` rather than `ssh` to push to your repository, hence not using your `ssh` key.

Some steps to change the URL for your remote repository:

```sh
git remote -v
# Should see
# origin   https://gitlab.name.com/project/repo.git (fetch)
# origin   https://gitlab.name.com/project/repo.git (push)

git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.name.com:project/repo.git
# you should be able to get the SSH url from the GitLab UI if in doubt

git remote -v
# verify changes
# origin   git@gitlab.name.com:project/repo.git (fetch)
# origin   git@gitlab.name.com:project/repo.git (push)
```

Comment: I've change https to ssh as you wrote but there is another error message: Push failed
Remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project
Could not read from remote repository.
   
   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.


Day before that problem I used Charles. Could it change some settings?

Answer (score 2):

> I've change https to ssh as you wrote but there is another error message:
>
> Push failed Remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project Could not read from remote repository.

Test your SSH authentication with, in command-line:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.name.com
```

You will check if your new SSH key is indeed considered or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add yourself as a project member.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).